# Given a bigger matrix and a smaller matrix check if the smaller matrix can be found in bigger matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

sample input:

3(int)

1 1 1

2 2 2

3 3 3       #(matrix)

2(int)

1 1

2 2#(matrix)

```
enter code here

a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
    l = list(map(int,input().split())
b = int(input())
for j in range(b):
    l1 = list(map(int,input().split())
if l1 in l:
   print("true")
else:
   print("False")
```

it needs to show "true" but it always show "False".

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator doesn't work in your case. You must iterate over each value of your bigger matrix, check if the value corresponds to the first value of the smaller matrix and then, if True, check if all the following values correspond to the values of the smaller matrix.

```
def is_matrix_contained(bigger: list[list[int]], smaller: list[list[int]]) -> bool:
    for row_ind, row in enumerate(bigger[:len(bigger) - len(smaller) + 1]):
        for col_ind, col in enumerate(row[:len(bigger) - len(smaller) + 1]):
            if col == smaller[0][0]:
                is_contained = True
                for i in range(len(smaller)):
                    for j in range(len(smaller[0])):
                        if bigger[row_ind + i][col_ind + j] != smaller[i][j]:
                            is_contained = False
                            break
                    if not is_contained: break
                if is_contained: return True
                else: break
    return False
```

This will take 2D lists as parameter, so you will have to change the way you get inputs from user :

```
a = int(input())
l = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for _ in range(a)]
b = int(input())
l1 = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for _ in range(b)]
if is_matrix_contained(l, l1):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```